# try to install MySQL-python on Mac but keeping get errors

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pip, mysql-python

I use python 2.7 on Mac 10.13
I already have MySQL on my Mac, but when I wanna install MySQL-python, keep getting error.

I tried pip:

> sudo pip install mysql-python

but got:

```
 Collecting mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 1.9MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-AhyoBa/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-AhyoBa/mysql-python/
```

Then I tried to move the file directly to 'site-package',and ran:

```
python /Users/dandizhao/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup.py install
```

but still got:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dandizhao/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/Users/dandizhao/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup_posix.py", line 32, in get_config
    metadata, options = get_metadata_and_options()
  File "/Users/dandizhao/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.5/setup_common.py", line 12, in get_metadata_and_options
    metadata = dict(config.items('metadata'))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 642, in items
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'metadata'
```

Really exhausted...I tried many methods I can find, but none of them works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went on [this link here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/169) and it seems like this is a very common issue with MySQL and MacOS.

Give these commands a try in your terminal

```
$ brew uninstall mysql
$ brew install mysql-connector-c
$ brew unlink mysql-connector-c
$ brew install mysql
$ pip install mysql-python
```